# Why Javascript click() will override

Tags: javascript, triggers, download, click, href

I have a question haunted me,

CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyZWex

Maybe the link in the array not available anymore when you opened it.

**The purpose is when a user clicked the download button, then will download all the `files` in the array.**

As you can see the CodePen, I have two buttons,
one will run the function with setTimeout and one will not.
Both functions have for loop and set `a` attribute `href` in every loop.
The question is I just need to set the click() timeout can fulfill the purpose, but why? The `click()` will override?

I don't see any mention trigger multiple `click()` will ignore or something else on MND website. anybody knows?

```js
let files = ["http://cdl54.convert2mp3.net/download.php?id=youtube_JXM2mGrCx7Y&key=QjljZm6W9BG5&d=y",
"http://cdl13.convert2mp3.net/download.php?id=youtube_qr1-EhAS1zY&key=feP73R2lI3TJ&d=y",
"http://cdl6.convert2mp3.net/download.php?id=youtube_C9UTCQhxG0A&key=1BGu7LRW8ZiE&d=y",
"http://cdl16.convert2mp3.net/download.php?id=youtube_ANBYcvxEuFY&key=rAp4KQsqXC5H&d=y"];

var delay = document.getElementById('delay');
var notDelay = document.getElementById('notDelay');

delay.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var prev = false;
  for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    (function(i){
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.setAttribute('href', files[i]);
      prev ? setTimeout(()=>{ a.click(); }, 1000 * i) : a.click();
      prev = true;
    })(i);
  }
});

notDelay.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++){
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('href', files[i]);
    a.click();
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="delay">DOWNLOAD with setTimeout</button>

<button id="notDelay">DOWNLOAD without setTimeout</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the window.open(URL) function. (sry cant comment)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my question is why the click will override not other solution. I already achieve my purpose but I want to know why I need to setTimeout the `click()`